# Stop the Zeta function from evaluating

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, evaluation

I have a function `F` whose power series i want to find using `Series`.

It gives me the result I want, except there is a term of $\pi^4/10800$, and i want it to tell me if the result is `Zeta[2]^2/300`  or `Zeta[4]/120`. Is there a way to force the `Zeta` function to not evaluate?

```
F[x] = Integrate[Binomial[x, k], {k, 0, x}];
Series[F[x], {x, 0, 3}] // TeXForm
```

> $x+\frac{\pi ^2 x^3}{36}+O\left(x^4\right)$

I want the output to be $x+x^3\frac{\zeta(2)}{6}$ instead.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block) [`Zeta`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Zeta) so that it doesn't evaluate:

```
Block[{Zeta=Inactive[Zeta]},
    Series[F[x],{x,0,6}]
] //TeXForm
```

> $x+\frac{1}{6} x^3 \operatorname{Zeta}(2,1)-\frac{1}{6} x^4 \operatorname{Zeta}(3)+\frac{1}{60} x^5
>    \left(\operatorname{Zeta}(2,1)^2+9 \operatorname{Zeta}(4,1)\right)+x^6 \left(-\frac{1}{30} \operatorname{Zeta}(3)
>    \operatorname{Zeta}(2,1)-\frac{2 \operatorname{Zeta}(5)}{15}\right)+O\left(x^7\right)$

Comment: You could postprocess the result with `res /. Inactive[Zeta][s_, 1] :> Inactive[Zeta][s]`.

Comment: Also it's strange `Inactive[Zeta]` doesn't format in TraditionalForm with `ζ`.

Comment: @ChipHurst  What about `res1=res /. Inactive[Zeta][s_ , 1] :> \[Zeta][s] /. 
 Inactive[Zeta][s_ ] :> \[Zeta][s]` ? And if you want to activate it, `res1 /.\[Zeta][s_] :> Zeta[s]`

Comment: @ChipHurst That seems to have changed. In V12, I get `ζ` in `TraditionalForm` for `Inactive[Zeta][n]`.