# Mathematica command to convert $\pi^{2n}$ to $\zeta(2n)$

Tags: special-functions, summation

Is there a command on Mathematica that helps me to get the answer of some harmonic series in terms on $\zeta(2n)$ instead of $\pi^{2n}$? Let me give you an example:

The command :

```
Sum[HarmonicNumber[n, 5]/n^8, {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

gives :

$$-(1/63) [\pi]^6 \zeta[7] - (13/15) [\pi]^4 \zeta[9] - 
 55 [\pi]^2 \zeta[11] + 644 \zeta[13]$$

I know converting $\pi^2$, $\pi^4$ and $\pi^6$ to $\zeta(2)$ , $\zeta(4)$ and $\zeta(6)$ is not a big deal but I deal with harmonic series a lot and converting is time consuming. Also I deal with  harmonic series of high height which means more converting to do. So is there any command that gives the answer of the harmonic sum in terms of $\zeta(2n)$ instead of $\pi^{2n}$?

Thank you.

Comment: See [Stop the Zeta function from evaluating](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181160/stop-the-zeta-function-from-evaluating) for a related question.

Comment: Perhaps `sum /. Pi^n_?EvenQ :> Inactive[Zeta][n] // TraditionalForm`

Comment: Thank you Carl and Michael.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can make use of `Simplify` with `Assumptions`

I. Compute the sum

```
s=Sum[HarmonicNumber[n,5]/n^8,{n,1,Infinity}]
(* -(1/63) π^6 Zeta[7]-13/15 π^4 Zeta[9]-55 π^2 Zeta[11]+644 Zeta[13] *)
```

II. Make a table of `Zeta`-functions with even arguments

```
t=Flatten[Table[{ζ[2n]==Zeta[2n]},{n,0,6}]]
(* {ζ[0]==-(1/2),ζ[2]==π^2/6,ζ[4]==π^4/90,ζ[6]==π^6/945,ζ[8]==π^8/9450,ζ[10]==π^10/93555,ζ[12]==(691 π^12)/638512875} *)
```

III. Simplify with assumptions

```
Simplify[s/.{π->x,Zeta[n_]->ζ[n]},Assumptions->t/.{π->x}]
(* -15 ζ[6] ζ[7]-78 ζ[4] ζ[9]-330 ζ[2] ζ[11]+644 ζ[13] *)
```

Comments:

1. A much cleaner solution would be to use [the method of Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181160/stop-the-zeta-function-from-evaluating) to deactivate the `Zeta`function. However, it only works if the sum can be computed in the desired terms, i.e., in terms of `Zeta[2n+1]` and `Zeta[2n]`. This seems not to be the case.
2. The present method only replaces the occurrences of $\pi^{2n}$ for $n\ge1$. *The zeroth-order term is left unchanged.* Below I show how `Zeta[0]` can be taken into account.

**Different approach using** `SolveAlways`

Define some functions

```
Clear[sf,sx,sxx]
sf[a_,b_]:=Sum[HarmonicNumber[n,a]/n^b,{n,1,Infinity}]/.{Zeta[n_]->ζ[n]}
sxx[c_]:=Sum[a[i]ζ[i]Zeta[c-i],{i,c,Floor[c/2],-2}]
sx[c_]:=Sum[a[i]ζ[i]ζ[c-i],{i,c,Floor[c/2],-2}]
```

Let us try

```
k=5;l=8;
sx[k+l]/.First[SolveAlways[(sf[k,l]==sxx[k+l]),Table[ζ[i],{i,k+l,Floor[(k+l)/2],-2}]]]
(* -15 ζ[6] ζ[7]-78 ζ[4] ζ[9]-330 ζ[2] ζ[11]-1288 ζ[0] ζ[13] *)
```

Comment: Thank you sir that's very helpful

Comment: so what zeta(0) in the answer stands for ?

Comment: $\zeta(0)=-\tfrac12$ as follows from the integral representation or from the analytic continuation of series. The series representation of $\zeta(s)$ converges only for $\mathrm{Re}s>1$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function). See also here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404401/riemann-zeta-function-at-zero

Comment: Thanks ... all clear now.